# Adding Class To Crispy Checkboxes

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I am rendering an 'InlineCheckboxes' which will allow the user to select multiple checkboxes. I can give the whole element a class, but cannot figure out how to set classes to the individual checkbox options. I am wanting to give each a col-3 so they will align neatly.

I have been stuck on this for days and read everything I can find on it but still cant figure it out.

form.py

```
preferred_topics = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=TOPICS, required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NeedsAnalysisForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
        self.helper.layout = Layout(            
            '[..text form..]', '[..text form..]', InlineCheckboxes('preferred_topics'), '[..text 
            form..]')
```

What is rendered:

```
<div id="div_id_preferred_topics" class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="">
        Preferred topics
    </label>
    <div class="">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="preferred_topics" 
                id="id_preferred_topics_1" value="ANI">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="id_preferred_topics_1">
                Animals
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="preferred_topics" 
                id="id_preferred_topics_2" value="ART">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="id_preferred_topics_2">
                 Art
            </label>
        </div>
[..cont..]
```

but what I want is:

```
<div id="div_id_preferred_topics" class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="">
        Preferred topics
    </label>
    <div class="">
        <div class="col-3 custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="preferred_topics" 
                id="id_preferred_topics_1" value="ANI">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="id_preferred_topics_1">
                Animals
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="preferred_topics" 
                id="id_preferred_topics_2" value="ART">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="id_preferred_topics_2">
                 Art
            </label>
        </div>
[..cont..]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `{{form | crispy}}` you can use following

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


<form action="" method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form %}

        <div class="col-3 custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
            {{field|as_crispy_field}}
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{field.id_for_label}}">{{field.label}}</label>
        </div>

    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

<form>
```

Alternatively Using the crispy forms API, we can create a new template for this custom field in our “templates” folder:

> custom_checkbox.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_field %}

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    {% crispy_field field 'class' 'custom-control-input' %}
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now we can create a new crispy field, either in our forms.py module or in a new Python module named fields.py or something.

> forms.py

```
from crispy_forms.layout import Field

class CustomCheckbox(Field):
    template = 'custom_checkbox.html'
```

We can use it now in our form definition:

> forms.py

```
class CustomFieldForm(AddressForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Column('email', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                Column('password', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                css_class='form-row'
            ),
            'address_1',
            'address_2',
            Row(
                Column('city', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                Column('state', css_class='form-group col-md-4 mb-0'),
                Column('zip_code', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),
                css_class='form-row'
            ),
            CustomCheckbox('check_me_out'),  # <-- Here
            Submit('submit', 'Sign in')
        )
```

For more details refer [Django Crispy Forms layouts docs](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html)